# Why isn't cosmic microwave background radiation on Earth drowned out by thermal noise

Tags: electromagnetism, thermodynamics, thermal-radiation, experimental-technique

The Penzias/Wilson experiment, which detected the CMB, doesn't sound feasible given thermal noise.

> When Penzias and Wilson reduced their data they found a low, steady, mysterious noise that persisted in their receiver. This residual noise was 100 times more intense than they had expected.

**The receiver was still "hot".** The receiver was cooled to 4K, which is warmer than the 2.7 K. There is no way with horns, antennas, etc to concentrate the 2.7K CMB as it's incoherent black body ration, yet somehow they inadvertently got the CMB to be 100 fold above the 4K thermal noise!?

> They were certain that the radiation they detected on a wavelength of 7.35 centimeters did not come from the Earth, the Sun, or our galaxy.

At 7.35 cm (4.1 GHz) the atmosphere attenuates about 0.08 dB/km, see [here](http://www.rfcafe.com/references/electrical/images/atm_absorption.gif), mainly from oxygen. Going straight up is equivalent to about 8.4 km of air at sea level, so the attenuation is about 0.67 dB, or 15% is blocked. Since absorption = emission, the air is about 15% as bright as a black body. A black body at air temperature would radiate about 80 times as much at 4 GHz (and much more at higher frequencies) than the CMB. With 15% emission that is about 12 times as much radiation.

Who don't these thermal sources swamp the CMB signal?

Comment: ... and if your receiver picks up 13/12 of the signal you expected to pick up, then you need to explain where the last twelfth comes from.

Comment: But the "12" is not always 12. Temperature and (liquid) cloud droplets may absorb/emit more as well.

Comment: "There is no way with horns, antennas, etc to concentrate the 2.7K CMB as it's incoherent black body ration, yet somehow they inadvertently got the CMB to be 100 fold above the 4K thermal noise!?" - Take 100 antennas, each with a receiver with an SNR = 1. Point all of them at the same direction. You get 100 times the same correlated signal and 100 times uncorrelated receiver noise. Add the noisy signals. The SNR is now 10. Now work your way backwards and think about what a horn antenna does... as an impedance transformer. What does that mean for the signal to noise ratio?

Comment: Your assumption that the CMB is not correlated is false, by the way. It doesn't have temporal correlation, but it has spatial (well, angular) correlation.

Comment: Where are you taking your quotes from?  Doesn't your source direct you to an account which addresses your doubt?

Comment: @CuriousOne: So the CMB antennas can be many wavelengths apart and still get a correlated signal (as long as the point the same way)? But BB radiation doesn't have long-range spatial correlation, so the CMB is very different than being in a 2.7 K black room, even if has the same spectra?

Comment: You can check that with light at home. Let sunlight fall on a pinhole and observe it from far away. Even though the frequency characteristics of the light (its spectrum) hasn't changed, it can be used quite nicely for interference experiments. In case of the CMB the "pinhole" is billions of light years away. This smoothes out wavefronts and leads to spatial correlation, even if there is no temporal correlation. So, yes, the characteristics of a distant black body radiator are very different from the characteristics of a close one or, that of a black body cavity radiator.

Comment: This, by the way, has very important implications for the information content of the CMB. If it was different everywhere, it would contain an enormous amount of information about the early universe. In reality, though, we have already seen almost everything there is to see. The total information content is no larger than a few thousand bits, or so, and it can all be compressed into the spatial spectrum. That, if you will, is all the information that the big bang has left for us in the em spectrum. There may be some more in the gravitational wave spectrum, but we haven't detected that, yet.

Comment: @CuriousOne: Like a pinhole, the CMB is much farther away than it's size (due to the expansion of the universe, even though it is in all directions). Somehow this expansion expanded the spatial correlation distance much more than the CMB photon wavelengths? At least it's good news if you are trapped in inter-cluster space: you can add a rectifier to the horn to make a Brownian ratchet that relies on these correlations to extract energy -:).

Comment: It has nothing to do with the expansion. If you are much farther away from a point source than a wavelength, then the wavefront starts flattening out. The superposition of many flat wavefronts is a flat wavefront, so it doesn't matter that there are many small emitters far away. This is simply Huygen's principle at work.